# How to Extend JavaScript with global method like .toLowerCase()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I'm trying to find out how to extend JavaScript with some of my own methods similar to toLowerCase()

Say I wanted a capitalize() or addUnderscores(), really whatever.  I'm assuming there is a way to extend or overwrite existing ones.

Also is there a way to do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with jQuery. Just extend the `prototype` of the specific type you need...

```
if (!String.prototype.capitalize) {
    String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
        return this.toUpperCase();
    }
}

'foobar'.capitalize(); // 'FOOBAR'
```

In the function, `this` will be the string on which you called the method.

Comment: Although I'd assume `capitalize` to be more `return this.slice(0,1).toUpperCase()+this.slice(1)` :)

Comment: @tkone: Yeah, that would make more sense. Didn't really think that one through. :)

Comment: I mean your answer was right in point so like +1 anyway though :)